# Trigger a script on WiFi connect-disconnect event in raspberry Pi

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian, wpa-supplicant

I am a newbie with Raspberry Pi. I am having one Pi3 and one Pi Zero. Pi3 is acting as a router and my PiZero is connected with it.

I want to trigger a script on connect-disconnect event. I have configured the SSID and password in the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file. How can I ensure that my script is triggered when WiFi connection is established/broken?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You may write a [wpa_cli action script](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#wpa_cli_action_script).e,g:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$2" in
    CONNECTED)
        notify-send "WPA supplicant: connection established";
        ;;
    DISCONNECTED)
        notify-send "WPA supplicant: connection lost";
        ;;
esac
```

use `wpa_cli -a /path/to_your/script.sh` (make it executable) to perform action on connect.

If you need more custom stuff you can put a script in crontab. For example to keep it simple you may determine online/offline status by pinging wlan gateway...

Comment: used this command wpa_cli -a /home/pi/run_on_connect.sh (made it executable). but the output is showing selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0' and then blank. I wrote a script something like wlan='/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 |grep inet | wc -1' if [ $wlan -eq 0 ];then echo NOT CONNECTED else echo CONNECTED

Comment: If you run manually the script expected output is correct? There are some syntax errors to me.

Comment: yeah, I ran the script manually and the output is correct. wpa_cli -a command seems something wrong.

Comment: Take a look here: Arch documentation but should fit https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant
It's a daemon running, so put it in the background to test and use its builtin variables to determine connection/disconnection events.

Comment: @narutouzumaki Were you trying to use the P2P wifi interface? If you were trying to manage connections to a normal access point, maybe you should try `wpa_cli`'s `-i` argument to specify the desired interface.